# How do I replace caps in URL in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics account for a site I now am helping with. There is a history where no filters were applied and I would like to apply a filter to make all the URLs lowercase to match them up.

I see plenty on removing querystrings and such but nothing along the lines of replacing all uppercase chars with lowercase ones.

I already have a filter for data going forward but need to do it with older data 
if I can.

Is it possible?

Comment: This is better suited for the Webmasters forum as it is not related to coding. But to comment, you can create a "Lowercase" filter on whatever it is you are trying to change, that would apply to data going forward only (not retroactive).

Comment: nyuen - yes I already have that in place -

Comment: Seems this was posted on Stack Overflow earlier. It's best to ask for questions to be migrated to another site prior to posting there, so that we don't end up with [cross-posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) and duplicates if they are migrated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to alter historical data with any kind of GA filter. Filters only apply to data going forwards in time.

If you want, you can apply a "Lowercase" filter.

Comment: How would the user apply a filter going forward if that is what they want?? I do not pay attention to GA enough to know. But this could be an opportunity to help a user. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @closetnoc. Actually, I replied to OP already in SO where this question originally came from. :)

Comment: Ah yeah. Cross posting has been happening a lot lately! Good for you!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply a filter to historical data. All filters in Google Analytics are applied only to data forward.

Comment: Eduardo - I would think you could use the 'Search and Replace' filter to do it but not sure what to put in the 'Search string' or the 'Replace string'

Comment: Search and Replace filters will also only work going forward, and cannot be used to edit historical data.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to download the historical data into a CSV file, and then alter the data there using the spreadsheet program of your choice. It might take a little work, but it'll get the job done.